# Yammer Activity changes Message

Tags: yammer

Is it possible to use a URL in both a message and an activity in Yammer ?

1. Using the messages API, it is possible to construct a message which is:

   - Properly linked (in this example clicking on Title goes to example.com/id/1/); and
   - Includes an image (placehold.it/100x100).

For example:

```
#!/bin/bash
GROUP={GROUP}
TOKEN={TOKEN}
curl -X POST \
    -H "Authorization: Bearer $TOKEN" \
    --data "body=hello" \
    --data "group_id=$GROUP" \
    --data "og_fetch=false" \
    --data "og_url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.example.com%2Fid%2F2%2F" \
    --data "og_title=Title" \
    --data "og_image=http%3A%2F%2Fplacehold.it%2F100x100" \
    --data "og_description=Description" \
    --data "og_object_type=page" \
    --data "og_private=true" \
    https://www.yammer.com/api/v1/messages.json
```

2. Using the activity API it is possible to make an Open Graph object:

Example:

```
#!/bin/bash
TOKEN={TOKEN}
EMAIL={EMAIL}
curl -X POST \
    -H "Content-type: application/json" \
    -H "Accept: application/json" \
    -H "Authorization: Bearer $TOKEN" \
    -d '{"activity":{"actor":{"email":"'$EMAIL'"},"action":"create","object":{"url":"http://www.example.com/id/1/","image":"http://placehold.it/110x110","title":"Title","type":"page"}},"private":"false","message":"This is an update"}' \
    https://www.yammer.com/api/v1/activity.json
```

The problem is that now the original message from Step 1:

- No longer links to the actual content (it links to https://www.yammer.com/{network}/graph/{id})
- Loses its image (it is now mug0.assets-yammer.com/mugshot/images/75x75/3rd_party.png)

As an aside, the open graph object doesn't update for the new image provided in the activity post (110x110 vs 100x100). The docs (https://developer.yammer.com/v1.0/docs/open-graph) say "when an OG object exists (with the same URL), it is updated appropriately."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In one example you have the open graph object set to private and the other is to public. That may be causing the weird issue you are seeing. 
"og_private=true"